# How to run bash script only if passed a day?

Tags: bash, date

I'd like to run my script often (not by cron but manually) but some slow parts like `apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade` should be run max once per day.

I think to save last execution time in `/tmp/last_update.txt` and check if it's more than `now - 86400` but cannot understand how to make it nice with bash.

Cron is not accepted - it's dangerous to run these actions without checking application after that. Also during these tasks app is unstable and no need to run it every day - only when running script manually (deploying an app) but not more often than once per day.

**Example:**

```
some-fast-command-1

if [ not-run-command-2-for-24h ]; then
    some-slow-command-that-makes-app-unstable

    date > /tmp/last-run-command-2 # save last run time somehow
fi

some-fast-command-3
```

How to write `not-run-command-2-for-24h` condition the bash way?

In PHP I'd done something like

```
<?php
$filename = '/tmp/last-run-command-2';
$needRun = (!is_file($filename) && time() > file_get_contents($filename) + 86400);
if ($needRun) {
    run();
    file_put_contents($filename, time());
}
```

Comment: Well exact those types of tasks cron is designed for, not using it feels like reinventing the wheel again.

Comment: This is just an example. I have several types of tasks like this (clearing app cache) and it's not good to run them anytime - only when I run them manually on deploy and check manually if everything still works well.

Comment: Why do you want to limit how many times you run these commands?

Comment: They are slow and during execution application may be unstable. Developers may want to deploy application 10 times per hour, but there is no need to rebuild cache each time - once per day is enough.

Comment: For my understanding, are you looking for a *warning* if it is more than a day ago, make it *run* if it is more than a day? Warn you if day passes?

Comment: I think you need to expand on your original question.  I don't fully understand the problem.  If you have a script, you write conditionals, if it passes run the next script, unless it has been ran in the past 24 hours, etc.

Comment: I've added example and PHP code that may give an idea what do I need.

Answer (score -1):

I've found an answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/163570/26790

You can get current timestamp:
`now=$(date --date=$(date --iso-8601) +%s 2>/dev/null)`

Load timestamp from file:
`stamp=$(date --date=$(date -r $stamp_file --iso-8601) +%s 2>/dev/null)`

Compare:
`delta=$(($now-$stamp))`
`interval=$(($interval*60*60*24))`
`if [ $delta -ge $interval ]; then`

Comment: This doesn't work as expected.... `now=$(date --date=$(date --iso-8601) +%s` gives midnight of the current day.. if you run your script at 11:59 pm, and again two minutes later at 00:01 am, it will behave as if 24h have passed.